# Signal handling and sigemptyset()

Tags: c, process, signals, posix

Could anyone please explain in a really easy way to understand what sigemptyset() does? Why is it useful? I've read a bunch of definitions but i just don't understand. From what i gather it tracks the signals that are being used for blocking purposes? I'm not really sure i understand why that would be useful. Is it so we do not get that specific signal recursively?

Basic example where sigemptyset() is used:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

struct sigaction act;
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
act.sa_handler=function_name;
act.sa_flags=0;

sigaction(SIGINT, &act, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`sigemptyset` simply initializes the `signalmask` to empty, such that it is guaranteed that no signal would be masked. (that is, all signals will be received) Basically it is similar to a `memset(0)` but you don't have to know the details of the implementation. So if the `sa_mask` member is changed you don't need to adjust your code because it will be taken care of by `sigemptyset`.

Answer (score 10):

Take a step back.  `sigset_t` is a construct that represents multiple signals upon which some action is going to be take via some system call (e.g. `sigaction`) but since the data structure representing `sigset_t` is opaque there needs to be a reliable way to initialize it.  Local variables in C aren't automatically initialized and you can't just assume sigset_t is an integer type and initialize it to zero because it might be a structure or some other unknown type.  Thus `sigemptyset` and `sigfillset` are provided to reliably empty (turn all signals off) or fill (turn all signal on) the `sigset_t` representation.

Your actual confusion may be what the signal sets inherent in sigset_t are used for and the answer to that is they are used for multiple things.  You may want to block multiple signals in one call by passing a set to appropriate call.  Or you may want to check all pending signals in one call.  In short, it depends, but a set allows you to operate on multiple signals in one shot rather than a sequential series of actions - something which is particularly problematic with signals because they are asynchronous and subject to all kinds of race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The name says it all. `sigemptyset()` empties (a variable describing) a set of signals.

That is

```
sigset_t ss;
sigemptyset(&ss);
```

initialises a variable of type `sigset_t` (`ss` here) to "contain" no signals.

From [`man sigemptyset` (Linux)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigsetops.3.html):

> sigemptyset() initializes the signal set given by set to empty, with all signals excluded from the set.
>
> [...]
>
> Objects of type sigset_t must be initialized by a call to either **sigemptyset()** or **sigfillset()** before being passed to the functions **sigaddset()**, **sigdelset()** and **sigismember()** [...]

From the [POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigemptyset.html):

> ```
> int sigemptyset(sigset_t *set);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The **sigemptyset()** function initializes the signal set pointed to by set, such that all signals defined in POSIX.1-2008 are excluded.

Comment: *The name says it all* - well actually it's a pretty bad name in that case. It should be called sigset_empty or something.

Comment: No, but possibly `sig_emptyset`. The vast majority of functions defined in `signal.h` in POSIX have a `sig` prefix to indicate this. Thus `sigemptyset` is `signal.h`'s implementation to empty a set.