# Why doesn't this process handle a SIGUSR1 anymore?

Tags: c, signals, fork, signal-processing

I've got to solve a synchronization problem between two processes and I've got to do it with signals.

Two processes should do a given amount of work, and then signal the other one. This will happen indefinitely.

What happens with my code is:

I send a signal to the parent process, who sends a signal to the child process, who sends a signal to the parent process again, whom is halted and doesn't act anymore.

Ideally, parent and child should signal each other indefinitely.

```
int main () {
    parent_pid = getpid();

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        syserr_quit("fork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        signal(SIGUSR2, child_work);
        while (1) {}
    } else {
        child_pid = pid;

        signal(SIGUSR1, parent_work);
        while (1) {}
    }
}

void child_work (int signo) {
    sleep(1); // fake child work

    if (kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR1) < 0) syserr_quit("kill error");

    // wait for parent signal
    pause();
}

void parent_work (int signo) {
    sleep(1); // fake parent work

    if (kill(child_pid, SIGUSR2) < 0) syserr_quit("kill error");

    // wait for child signal
    pause();
}
```

Can't figure out what's wrong since it's a really small amount of code and everything seems to be in place to me.

If somebody wants to spin it up on their machine, here's [a full demo](https://pastebin.com/EJcGnGey) that works after a copy/paste.

---

## Update: sigaction(3) instead of signal(2)

As per some comments, I resort to the use of `sigaction` to avoid race condition and stopped using `sleep` in the demo.
Docs state that to avoid signal reception from being blocked during the execution of a handler, one must set the `SA_NODEFER` flag.

Code still behaves faulty, only this time is the child that stops receiving signals.

Snippet is the same as above with the exception of `signal` being swapped – both times – with

```
struct sigaction action;
action.sa_handler = parent/child_work;
action.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
sigaction(signo, &action, NULL);
```

---

*Full code*

To start the signaling, check the  from the console and send a signal (i.e. `kill -SIGUSR1 <parentid>`)

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void parent_work(int signo);
void child_work(int signo);

void syserr_quit(char *msg);

pid_t parent_pid;
pid_t child_pid;

int main () {
    parent_pid = getpid();
    printf("parent pid: %d\n", parent_pid);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        syserr_quit("fork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        struct sigaction action;
        action.sa_handler = child_work;
        action.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
        sigaction(SIGUSR2, &action, NULL);
        while (1) {}
    } else {
        child_pid = pid;
        printf("child pid: %d\n", pid);

        struct sigaction action;
        action.sa_handler = parent_work;
        action.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);
        while (1) {}
    }
}

void child_work (int signo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i); // fake child work

    // signal parent that a write is now possible
    printf("send signal to %d\n", parent_pid); fflush(stdout);
    if (kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR1) < 0) syserr_quit("kill error");
    printf("signal sent\n"); fflush(stdout);

    // wait for parent signal
    pause();
}

void parent_work (int signo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i); // fake child work

    // signal child that a read is possible
    printf("send signal to %d\n", child_pid); fflush(stdout);
    if (kill(child_pid, SIGUSR2) < 0) syserr_quit("kill error");
    printf("signal sent\n"); fflush(stdout);

    // wait for child signal
    pause();
}

void syserr_quit(char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

## Fin

Alright, guys it seems the updated code didn't work just because I didn't correctly initialize the `sigaction` mask. It must be done with `sigemptyset` and you can find out why [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684290/signal-handling-and-sigemptyset).

More details in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43983567/2081434).

Comment: As presented, your code will not even compile.  The signal handlers reference undeclared variables, and all of your functions call undeclared function `syserr_quit()`.  This is a good start on a [mcve], but it's not there yet.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Let me read that. In the meantime, I provided a full, 60 lines working demo in the last line of the question.

Comment: Not sure if this is connected to your problem (because your code will not compile), but quote from the Linux `signal(2)` man page:  "*Avoid its
       use: use sigaction(2) instead.*".  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html

Comment: @cdarke compile-ready version in the bin provided on the last line. I'll write a `sigaction` version of the code asap.

Comment: is appears the you want to do all work in `child_work()` and `parent_work()` but both functions are only passed to `signal()` and not called directly and there's no`kill()` either. So ther's nothing to happen but two endless loops

Comment: btw. never perform complex work in signal handlers but only set flags etc.

Comment: @Ingo Leonhardt, The OP claims the parent gets killed the second time it receives a signal. Endless loop would be the desired behaviour for that demo.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt alright. This is just an exercise to get to know signal/handlers better though. No production by any means. P.S. There are two `kill` calls, inside of `if` statements.

Comment: "*If  the disposition is set to a function, **then first either the disposition is reset to SIG_DFL**, or the signal is blocked (see Portability below), and then handler  is  called with  argument  signum.*" Start by using `sigaction` and reducing your handler to nothing but a flag increment as previously suggested.

Comment: ok, the first signal comes frrom outside, Ive overlooked that ...

Comment: @ikegami yeah, that might be it

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt first signal yes, must be `kill -USR1 <parentpid>`

Comment: @ikegami I'll write, try and post `sigaction` version in the next 10 mins. Stay tuned.

Comment: You must also rid yourself of the notion of a re-entrant signal handler! Keep in mind that `sleep` will get interrupted by signals, so you can use `while (1) { sleep(1); if (signaled) { signaled = 0; ... } }`

Comment: @doplumi, as a rule, we do not rely on external sites for details of a question posed here.  The question is expected to be self-contained, which is why we ask for a minimal, *complete*, and verifiable example.  Not providing one in the question itself is one of the standard reasons for closing a question.  I have so far held off voting for closure for that reason, in the hope and expectation that the question can be brought up to standard without much additional work.

Comment: To amplify some of the other comments, signal handlers should do as little work as possible and return quickly, in part because that's an assumption of the design of that feature, but also because they are often limited in what they *can* do.  Signal handlers typically have a rather small stack to work with, and they are limited to calling only async-signal-safe functions, and modifying only automatic objects and `volatile` objects of type `sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: @cdarke, @ikegami, @John Bollinger: update with the use of `sigaction` and a for loop still doesn't work. Details in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

When your `SIGUSR1` signal handler `parent_work` is called, the `SIGUSR1` signal is either mapped to `SIG_DFL` (default signal handling) or ignored for the parent process (ref. [`signal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html)) :

> When a signal occurs, and func points to a function, it is implementation-defined whether the equivalent of a:
>
> ```
> signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
> ```
>
> is executed or the implementation prevents some implementation-defined set of signals (at least including sig) from occurring until the current signal handling has completed.

When the child process then generates the `SIGUSR1` signal again for the parent process, it will not invoke the `parent_work` signal handler again for that reason.

So, in your signal handler, you need to re-register the signal again if you want subsequent signals to also be handled by the signal handler :

```
void parent_work(int signo) {
    /* your handler code */
    signal(signo, parent_work);
}
```

Note that this still leaves room for a race condition - ie. if the second `SIGUSR1` arrives before the signal handler was re-registered. But really, that's intrinsic to your design.

There are of course better alternatives, and general advice. Some of which have been mentioned in comments already, so I will just refer to those if you're interested.

Comment: Note that the implementation-definedness inherent in the behavior of a signal handler registered via the `signal()` function is resolved by instead using `sigaction()` to register the handler.  Moreover, this mechanism makes it unnecessary for the handler to re-register itself (depending on which option is selected), and therefore allows the race condition to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the updated code didn't work just because I didn't correctly initialize the `sigaction` mask. It must be done with `sigemptyset` and you can find out why [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684290/signal-handling-and-sigemptyset).

Correct initialization of a `sigaction` for a signal that you want to be able to catch while the handler is executing would be:

```
struct sigaction sa;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
action.sa = handler;
action.sa = SA_NODEFER;
sigaction(signo, &sa, NULL);
```

---

*Final code*

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void parent_work(int signo);
void child_work(int signo);

void syserr_quit(char *msg);

pid_t parent_pid;
pid_t child_pid;

int main () {
    parent_pid = getpid();
    printf("parent pid: %d\n", parent_pid);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        syserr_quit("fork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        struct sigaction sa;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sa.sa_handler = child_work;
        sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
        sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL);
        while (1) {}
    } else {
        child_pid = pid;
        printf("child pid: %d\n", pid);

        struct sigaction sa;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sa.sa_handler = parent_work;
        sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
        while (1) {}
    }
}

void child_work (int signo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i); // fake child work

    // signal parent that a write is now possible
    printf("send signal to %d\n", parent_pid); fflush(stdout);
    if (kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR1) < 0) syserr_quit("kill error");
    printf("signal sent\n"); fflush(stdout);

    // wait for parent signal
    pause();
}

void parent_work (int signo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i); // fake child work

    // signal child that a read is possible
    printf("send signal to %d\n", child_pid); fflush(stdout);
    if (kill(child_pid, SIGUSR2) < 0) syserr_quit("kill error");
    printf("signal sent\n"); fflush(stdout);

    // wait for child signal
    pause();
}

void syserr_quit(char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```